# python formatting f" " operator exit status 0

Tags: python

update, the code was called from inside try block!
closing the thread. Thanks

I'm coding in python 3.6.3 and I encountered some issue with the f" " operator.

```
print(f"{foo}")
```

foo is not defined and the code will exit status 0 without printing.

I tried to google this issue and could not find something about it.
Also, tried to look at https://bugs.python.org/

how can I confirm its a bug and not fixed ?
how I report a bug ? can I report a bug ?

Thanks

Comment: That code prints the content of a variable named `foo`, so if there is no variable, it doesn't work

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is an issue with Python and not, as the error message is telling you, an issue in your code, that there is no variable named "foo".

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: What did you expect this code to do?

Comment: The burden of proof is on you to demonstrate that there is a program which will exit with status 0 without printing.

Answer (score 2):

This is **normal behaviour, it isn't a bug**. This is [`Formatted string literals (f-string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

---

The code `print(f"{foo}")` means to print the content the **variable** named `foo`, use like

```
foo = 5
print(f"{foo}")   # 5
print(f">{foo}<") # >5<

foo = "Hey You!"
bar = ['a', 5, True]
print(f"{foo}/{bar}")  # Hey You!/['a', 5, True]
print(f">{foo}<>{bar}<")  # >Hey You!<>['a', 5, True]<
```

To print  exactly `{foo}`, just use a basic string

```
print("{foo}") # {foo}
```

Comment: foo is not defined at all.

Comment: @oohayon I get it, that's why you have the ERROR `foo is not defined` . The code you show does USE a variable `foo`, what do you want ? What question do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

**Python will definitely exit when you try to use a variable before instantiating it and this is perfectly normal.**

"f" allows you to perform string interpolation in python.

What will work is:

```
foo = 'Hello World'

print(f'{foo}')
```

***Output : Hello World!***

---

```
foo = "Jim Jam"

print(f"Title : {foo}")
```

**Output : Title : Jim Jam**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `foo` is not defined at all in your code. You are attempting to use a variable without defining it. That isn't legal behavior in any language. You can certainly define it and set it to `None` and test that it isn't `None` in the formatted `str`. Like,

```
foo = None
print(f"{foo or 'No foo'}")
```

Outputs

```
No foo
```